# Export-SPWeb - Fails after a few minutes / Turn Sub Site into Site Collection

Tags: 2013, powershell, site-collection, export, sub-site

We have an Intranet SharePoint 2013 farm with 4 servers (2x WFE, 2x APP). Within our Intranet we have a 'Video Center' (~37GB) which at this point unfortunately is a sub-site. We want to turn it into a Site Collection via Export-/Import-SPweb.

When trying to export the site we get the following message after ~9GB / 114 cmp files (the disk has about 60GB of free space):

**Export-SPWeb : Failed to create package file.**

I used the following command for it:

**Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://intranet.doamin.com/video" -Path "C:\Temp\VideoCenter_Backup.cmp"**

Can anyone advise if I am missing an option in my command or what could be the reason for the error? Also maybe there is a better way to export/import a sub-site into a site collection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the size of your export package. There is a default cab size of about 25Mb - this used to be a limit you had to increase with stsadm by setting a parameter. With the PowerShell Export-SPWeb cmdlet it generates multiple files if you hit the limit. You may need to change this limit using the CompressionSize parameter to set the cab size (up to a maximum of 1024Mb).

> Export-SPWeb http://mysite -Path c:\backup\ExportFile -CompressionSize 1000

Comment: Tried it with several values over the weekend and what worked for me in the end (for the export) was selecting a smaller value (e.g.  -CompressionSize 50).

Selecting anything much higher resulted in this message being displayed and the command failing:
"Export-SPWeb : Export ran out of memory while compressing a very large file. To successfully export, turn compression off by specifying the -nofilecompression parameter."


But in the end I was able to achieve my goal using "Export-SPWeb http://mysite -Path c:\backup\ExportFile -CompressionSize 50" 


Thanks!

Comment: For a large list (in my case 75GB) running the Export-SPWeb with -NoFileCompression parameter was the most resource and time efficient. Additionally make sure to check the disk space of the source SharePoint server and destination and SQL server, the export/import fails if the backup is larger than the available disk space.